# Android - Add A Touch Event Listener To BMP

Tags: android, events, bitmap, touch

I have a bitmap:

```
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimage);
```

I want it so when a user presses on the bmp, I get a trace message (I will add in what I need it to do)

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be more appropriate to use an `ImageButton` rather than an `ImageView`. Although, you could implement the `onTouchEvent` and register a touch event listener on the main element that the Bitmap relies in.  Or, register an `onTouchListener` for the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `Bitmap` is a picture that can't exist on your layout without any container. A container for a picture in Android is `ImageView`. So to make a clickable `ImageView` with your picture inside you should use:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
imgView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
imgView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I've implemented that but i get the error:
Cannot instantiate the type View.OnClickListener

Comment: @JeffLemon, A strange error.. Please post your code and your xml layout

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set an ImageView's background Bitmap as bmp, and then set a click listener on the ImageView.

Take a look at ImageView's setImageBitmap method, and View.OnClickListener